# Unable to find source code of Media Extension

Tags: swift, core-data

I am new to iOS and currently studying https://github.com/yehorchernenko/private-files. In this project there is an extension "Media". I am unable to find Definition of Media Class. Where to find complete source code of Media Class? (After right clicking and Jump to Definition just show incomplete code)

Comment: Ask the author, yehorchernenko.

Comment: Go to `Private_Files.xcdatamodeld` and select `Data Model Inspector` see the `Codegen` is set as `Class definition`. You can change it to `Menual/None` or `Category/Extension` and create the Media class again from Editor option

Comment: Thank You Torongo, Please explain a little bit. From where to start i.e. Where is Private_Files.xcdatamodeld

Comment: Thanks Torongo for pointing out to Private_Files.xcdatamodeld